# Finding isolated links in a network of links with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, postgresql, st-touches

I have a street network from many of links in a PostgreSQL table. Some links have no connection to the network. I want to isolate these links from the network. Each link has a geometry (geom) and id column.

How can I get the linkids from the network, which don't touch any other links?
Maybe the function is st_touches, but how can I ask this on the whole network from each link?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On a properly noded network, you could use also use `st_intersects`

So, one could select all records where no other records (with a different ID) intersects. It would be querying the same layer twice:

```
SELECT l1.id
FROM links l1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1 
  FROM links l2
  WHERE l1.id != l2.id
  AND ST_INTERSECTS(l1.geom, l2.geom)
 )
```

Comment: I have a mistake of thought: the lines can be compound from more than one links. For my problem i need two steps. Step 1 should be to union all links  touching  the links tehreafter or bevor. After that in Step 2 isolate the links that have no connections to the network. How can i union the contiguous links to one line ?

Comment: You can use `ST_LineMerge` with `ST_Collect` to merge contiguous lines (keeping nodes of degree > 2).  The downside is that this loses attribution on the lines.